# Copying a list of files

Tags: linux, files, cp

I have a directory which has plenty of files which need to be copied over to another directory. Remember, not all files need to be copied, only some of them. Is there a way I can come up with a script to copy all these needed files from one directory to another instead of doing one by one.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? How would you know what files to copy?

Comment: What are the criteria that tell apart files to copy from the rest?

Comment: I did not try because I have about 100 files totally different names. How about if I put a script and list all those file names in one. and then run that script?

Comment: To make a reasonable script you need some pattern to follow when parsing the files. There is some pattern, a common characteristic in your files names? Check the answer below: *If the files have similar names... do...*. If there's no discernible pattern... well, there's not much to do.

Answer (score 4):

Given your comment on user79914's response, it sounds like you'll have to explicitly list the files you want copied in a regular old `cp` command. Something like the following should do the job:

```
cp FILE_1 FILE_2 FILE_3 /destination/directory
```

If, for instance, your copy operation is one you'll be doing more than once, you could do something like the following:

```
for FILE in $(cat ./list_of_files.txt)
do
    cp ${FILE} /destination/directory
done
```

This example assumes that you've added the list of desired files to the text file `list_of_files.txt`. The benefit of this approach, especially if you're having to perform the copy more than once, is that you can just add any new files you need copied to your `list_of_files.txt` file.

For more examples like this one, check out this link:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/

Comment: Well, since we need an explicit list anyway, why not just `cp FILE_1 FILE_2 FILE_3 /destination/directory/`? Side note: [quote variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618).

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the fastest and most pragmatic approach. My thought was that perhaps OP would want to expand on the loop their self, perhaps iterating through the contents of a text file containing the file names. This was mostly food for thought.

Comment: Hello Alex, so I am trying to understand this script file, sorry I am not good at writing script files. So looking at your script where you say                                   for FILE in FILE_1 FILE_2 FILE_3
do
    cp ${FILE} /destination/directory
done                                                                                                                                 In this, I need replace just the FILE_1 FILE_2 FILE_3 and so on with my file names, is that correct? The next line where you ay cp $FILE, that remains as is? Thanks

Comment: Hey mywayz, yes, you're right. I've gone ahead and edited my initial reply though. I think it may be easier to understand. It also addresses Kamil Maciorowski's feedback.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method doesn't require any scripting ability on your part.  It only requires a text editor.  Certainly there are more elegant and more generalized ways to do it, but sometimes one just wants to accomplish an immediate task without having to detour into a lot of learning curve climbing and such, if your scripting skills are at a novice level.

Let's suppose you have a file called `myfiles.txt` which contains a list of every filename you want to copy, one to a line.  I'm going to assume:

- you have fewer than one million files in the list
- each line of `myfiles.txt` contains the correct path and filename of that source file
- the directory path you're copying the files to is `test` and it already exists
- you have no problematic characters in your filenames like quotes, apostrophes, newlines and the like.

Now say:

```
vi myfiles.txt
:%s/^/cp -vp '/
:%s-$-' test/-
ZZ
```

That will edit your list of files to put `cp -vp '` at the beginning of every line (every filename), and put `' test/` at the end of every filename.

You now have a list of N `cp` commands that will copy your N files into the `test/` directory.  You can execute it by saying:

```
sh < myfiles.txt
```

Voila.

Comment: Hello Jim, when I do vi my file.txt and the file opens, then copy pasting the whole command from colon to ZZ closes the file with cp -vp just visible on the last row, basically with just the last file name. So unlike you said that it puts cp -vp at beginning of every file, its not doing that. Should I enter it separately instead of copy pasting.?

Comment: One line at a time should work.

Answer (score 0):

If the files have similar names, you could use a wildcard, like `cp test* ~/test/` to copy all files starting with 'test' to the ~/test directory.

To copy the visible (non-dot) files in the directory, you could do `cp ./* ~/test/` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, the files do not have similar names. Is there a way I can put all the needed files in one script file and then run that script which could copy all those files?